# ajax and no forms, what will happen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I notice my site does not have a single `<form>` with the exception of logging in. I am not sure how or why it happened but i found i use jquery and ajax to post everything then refresh (or not if i dont need to). How and why would the user suffer from this?

Some of my 'forms' include

1. Leaving a comment on a page
2. Removing messages
3. Sending a private message (which i then do document.location=nextPage)
4. Marking as a favourite.

Comment: Just see what happens when you disable javascript.

Comment: twodayslate: The site requires js to be friendly and i didnt bother to code an unfriendly version. I dont support not having js for this site in particular.

Answer (score 4):

Forgetting for a moment that none of the site would work without javascript disabled, another side effect you might not realize, is that there is no default `submit` behavior anymore. This means a user cannot finish typing their entry and hit enter to submit the form. This is important for *search forms* and the like, but less important for comment forms.

Wrapping form fields in a `form` tag and having a submit `input` element (even if it is `display:none`) allows for a default submit action on `enter` or `return`. If you do this, you simply call `preventDefault()` into the `submit()` event handler to stop the real submit, and make an AJAX one instead.

Ok, *back* to the JS disabled thought. You have to make a choice:

1. Work backwards to implement unobtrusive JS on your site. Basically, the site works with or without JS, but it will work better (or more refined) with JS enabled
2. *Or* place a prominent message alerting your users to the fact that your site requires JS for the site to work. The cons to this method is you might limit the usefulness of your site in some corporate networks and on some mobile devices. As far as people who willingly turn of JS, the alert can let them decide if they want to stay around or not.

Given that the site is already coded, take a look at your target audience and make your best decision given the time and energy required to make the site work without JS.

Comment: I completely forgot about default behavior. Luckily the only place that needs one is the login which does use the form. (I am not sure hitting enter in the subject area for PMs is required or important. but good place i may want it). +1.

Answer (score 4):

From your comment, I see that you don't intend to support users without JavaScript, so the accessibility and backward compatibility argument is moot.

However, you are likely creating a lot of unnecessary requests by posting with AJAX and then refreshing the page.  This is *not* how AJAX was intended to be used and is possibly an  anti-pattern.  The idea of AJAX is to send specific and receive specific data, and to *update* the page based on that received data, not refreshing.

Also, by not using form's, you disable the default submit functionality (pressing `<enter>`) as [Doug Neiner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285685/ajax-and-no-forms-what-will-happen/2285748#2285748) pointed out

Comment: +1. good point. I hope i can be not lazy and program more so the site doesnt require a refresh. But maybe i can POST somehow without using ajax. I'm going to search then ask how to do this in JS. Excellent point.

Comment: Thanks all. @acidzombie24 If you just use `<form method="post">` you can post without any JavaScript at all.

Comment: Other then my login (which is a plain form) most/all my forms have special data i grab with javascript and occasionally i have data inside of a div instead a dozen inputs for a dozen forms.