# How do i POST/Submit a form using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

From [This answer and the fact i may be using an anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285685/ajax-and-no-forms-what-will-happen/2285772#2285772) I thought i should change the ajax call into behavior like submitting a form. I found [$.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Post) but that seems to be doing ajax and does not change the page i am on.

How do i submit a form with jquery or plain JS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's as simple as calling the `$.submit()` method on the form itself:

```
$("#formID").submit(); // jQuery
document.getElementById("formID").submit(); // Javascript
```

Or if you're using the name attribute only:

```
$("form[name='formName']").submit(); // jQuery
document.formName.submit(); // Javascript
```

If you're only interested in redirecting the page after you submit the data, you could do this from the callback of the `$.post()` call:

```
$.post("process.php", { 'foo':$(".bar").val() }, function(result) {
  window.location = "thanks.php";
});
```

#### Update:

The asker indicated in the comments below that no form actually exists. I would suggest creating one:

```
var myForm = $("<form>")
               .attr({'method':'post','action':'process.php'})
               .appendTo("<body>");
```

And then adding your data:

```
$("<input>")
  .attr({'type':'hidden','name':'firstname'})
  .val("Jonathan")
  .appendTo(myForm);
```

And later, when you're ready, submit it:

```
$(myForm).submit();
```

Comment: problem is, i dont have a form. I grab the post data inside of a <div> add in a few more then need to send it. -edit- actually theres a few places were i get info from which made my code simpler to read and maintain. Problem is now i must either inject the data in a form when submitting or submit somehow via js

Comment: You should ask "how do I submit a form" if no form exists to submit :)

Comment: I would suggest creating a form element on the fly, then submitting that.

Comment: hmm, is there an easy way to do that? should i continue doing an ajax submit then window.location = url when it succeeds (and err msg on fail)? I;m thinking which one is easier to maintain and wont kill the server.

Comment: @acidzombie24: I don't know which is appropriate for your project. If you don't need the page to immediately redirect, you can stick with `$.post()` and simply change the `window.location` in the callback.

Comment: Great answer. It sounds like this behavior is only available with a form submit, which makes sense since you don't typically want to reload a page using javascript (and NOT have a form). That code looks simple so i guess i'll generate the input using a loop then submit. Great answer. +1 & accept

Answer (score 0):

You can also do so asynchronously

```
var params = { 'key1' : 'value1' , 'key2' : 'value2' };
$.post( '/site/resource/' , params , function(ret) { alert(ret) } );
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can submit as a get you could try some javascript like this:

```
window.location = 'http:/host/path?param=value&param=value&param=value'
```

You can even construct the string on the fly from all your data scattered in the DOM.